# Can I ask questions to proof-read my code?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a section of code that I have tested out, and it seems to be sound, but as a (very) amateur coder I am uncertain if it's overkill, or even contradictory.

**Can I post it as a question and ask people to proof read it for me?**

The reason I am asking here is because I haven't found anything saying I can't (yet), but at the same time, it doesn't seem like the proper thing to post on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *might* work on Stack Overflow, but it sounds *perfect* for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is there for exactly that. Your question will be in good company there.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know this existed, there are so many communities!

Comment: @Ben Check out https://stackexchange.com/sites in order to see a list and description of all Stack Exchange communities. You can also check http://area51.stackexchange.com/ in order to see the site proposals.